# HTML-Tidy documentation [tidyCreate() ??]

Tags: c, htmltidy

I want to add html-tidy in my C projects (http://www.html-tidy.org/). Even though, a lot of documentation links can be found at the official website. I can't find any details explanation on html-tidy library functions (like man).

A sample can be found on the official website and I would like to know how the following function is working :

```
tidyCreate();
```

Comment: http://api.html-tidy.org/tidy/tidylib_api_5.2.0/group__Basic.html#ga728e98da5985ecb26de7c6c45f7fcaf2

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the API doc. Now, I'd like to know if I run like a batch of HTML pages. Do I need to call each time "tidyCreate();" or I need to call it only once ?